# While editing the content of webview , scrollview won't move upwards and keyboard hides the lines

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios7, webview, uiwebview

I am developing an app as like rich editor text and as i have wrote the text on editable web view but keyboard hides the lines. I am also using some javascript coding but not succeeded.

```
this.updateOffset = function() {
    try{
        var sel = window.getSelection();
        range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
        if(this.tmpSpan==null){
            this.tmpSpan = document.createElement('span');
        }
        range.insertNode(this.tmpSpan);
        this.yOffset = this.tmpSpan.offsetTop;
        this.xOffset = this.tmpSpan.offsetLeft;
        this.tmpSpan.parentNode.removeChild(this.tmpSpan);
    }
    catch(exc){
        log('updateOffset:' + exc.toString());
    }
}

// eContent is the div with 'contenteditable', while visibleHeight is an int, set from objective-c (depending on where the webview is positioned, keyboard height and screen height)
this.scrollToVisible = function(){
    try {
        if(this.eContent.clientHeight>this.visibleHeight){
            this.updateOffset();
            if(this.yOffset<window.pageYOffset){
                window.scrollTo(0, this.yOffset);
            }
            else if(this.yOffset-window.pageYOffset>this.visibleHeight){
                window.scrollTo(0, this.yOffset-this.visibleHeight);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (exc){
        log('scrollToVisible: ', exc.toString());
    }
}
```

Please suggest what we should do.

Comment: Editable Web View ? Scroll view didn't scroll as like text view ? JavaScript coding? What are you talking about ? Please show your codes & storyboard .

Comment: Raptor, I have edited the description.

Comment: You are working on Cordova or making a mobile web? You didn't mention in question.

Comment: Oh! i am implementing ios(iPhone,iPad) Universal application.

Comment: Since you're using JavaScript to write "apps", which framework are you using? It's always better to use native codes via iOS SDK.